# pthread Linux data runtime

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, global-variables

I have threads in my application that wait on condition variable. When the codition is good thread starts to work and reads some data. My data is global variable. Is it possible pass data on runtime without using global data? I read something about specific data but i don't know if it is useful in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Can you expand on "pass data on runtime" ? Where does the data come from ?

Comment: i have a function that input one vector. The vector change on execution time. Thread work on this data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass this to your thread routine: `pthread_create(thread, attr, function, *USER_ARG*)`. Simply create a struct for the data you need for the thread to execute.

Where `*USER_ARG*` is stored in memory is important, you will often want to use the free store (`malloc` it) for the argument, otherwise you may corrupt the stack of the thread which called `pthread_create`.

Comment: the data change and i don't want create the thread each time.

Comment: you can still put that data into the struct you `malloc` and pass to the thread routine. if it works now using a single global variable, then just move that global into the struct you pass. if i am misunderstanding, then a code sample would help.